# Need this function to return false on weekend days

Tags: php, datetime, date-arithmetic

Need help with php.

So I am writing this for a shop. This function returns false whenever they are closed (opening at 9:30 and closing at 22:45).

I need it to ALSO return false when the current day of the week is Saturday or Sunday.

Here is the function:

```
function can_order_now_timeframe(){

 $morning= new DateTime("09:30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $night = new DateTime("22:45", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));


 $morning_u = $morning->format('U');
 $night_u = $night->format('U');

 $datenow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $timestampnow = $datenow->format('U');


 if(($morning_u<$timestampnow) && ($timestampnow < $night_u)){
 return true;
 }else{
 return false;
 }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So just check the day of the week in your final if statement

Comment: @JohnConde I am not a PHP programmer though. That's why I submitted this question. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the date object (credits to Icecub)

```
function isWeekend($datenow){
    $day = $datenow->format('%w');
    if ($day=="0"||$day=="6"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using date and strtotime in combination with the timestamp ($timestampnow)

If you have PHP >= 5.1:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

otherwise:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

A complete code would look like ths. (You can use a function inside a function)

```
<?php
function isWeekend($datenow){
    $day = $datenow->format('%w');
    if ($day=="0"||$day=="6"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function can_order_now_timeframe(){

    $morning= new DateTime("09:30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
    $night = new DateTime("22:45", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));


    $morning_u = $morning->format('U');
    $night_u = $night->format('U');

    $datenow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
    $timestampnow = $datenow->format('U');


    if(($morning_u<$timestampnow) && ($timestampnow < $night_u) && !isWeekend($datenow)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

or you can have it all inside one function like this if you dont think you might need the weekend detection again:

```
<?php
function can_order_now_timeframe(){
    $morning= new DateTime("09:30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
    $night = new DateTime("22:45", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));

    $morning_u = $morning->format('U');
    $night_u = $night->format('U');

    $datenow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
    $timestampnow = $datenow->format('U');

    $day = $datenow->format('%w');
    if ($day!="0" and $day!="6"){   
        if(($morning_u<$timestampnow) && ($timestampnow < $night_u)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: He's using DateTime objects and you're recommending `date()` and `strtotime()`? Not saying it's wrong, but surely very odd..

Comment: Indeed... lol But I find it much easier to do using strtotime(). He can pass on the formatted date to isWeekend() and get a fast TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: It's not that hard at all. Just `$day = $datenow->format('%w');` And after that just check if `$day` is 0 or 6

Comment: Just saying so you can edit your answer with it. I have no reason to create my own answer for this.

Comment: Np, adding it now

Comment: @icecub it would be much appreciated if you implemented it in the function though. I am not too well versed in PHP.

Comment: Yeah that's what i just did hehe

Comment: @PatrickSimard Thanks. :) So how could I add this function to the one I posted?

Comment: Added a complete exemple

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP >= 5.1:

```
function can_order_now_timeframe(){

 $morning= new DateTime("09:30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $night = new DateTime("22:45", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $morning_u = $morning->format('U');
 $night_u = $night->format('U');
 $datenow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $timestampnow = $datenow->format('U');
 if(($morning_u<$timestampnow) && ($timestampnow < $night_u) && !(date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6)){
     return true;
 }else {
     return false; 
 }
}
```

otherwise:

```
function can_order_now_timeframe(){

 $morning= new DateTime("09:30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $night = new DateTime("22:45", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $morning_u = $morning->format('U');
 $night_u = $night->format('U');
 $datenow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
 $timestampnow = $datenow->format('U');
 $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
 if(($morning_u<$timestampnow) && ($timestampnow < $night_u) && ($weekDay != 0 || $weekDay != 6)){
     return true;
 }else {
     return false; 
 }
}
```